# Recently loaded Kubuntu onto my Mac. Was looking for instructions on how to boot to Kubuntu instead of Mac iOS. Please advise. Thank you!

Tags: boot, kubuntu, mac

Recently loaded Kubuntu onto my Mac. Was looking for instructions on how to boot to Kubuntu instead of Mac iOS. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To boot into Kubuntu on a mac simply type the alt key when the screen begins lightning. You might have to press that key earlier but more than once to get it

Comment: I also have Macbooks and it works for every macbook out there